# Eigen, dot product method:

Tags: c++, eigen

I am converting some psuedo-code to actual c++.

The psuedo is:

```
float ac_ab_0 = acos(clamp(dot(
        normalize(c - a),
        normalize(b - a)), -1, 1));
```

My code is:

```
Eigen::Vector3f a = Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 0);
Eigen::Vector3f b = Eigen::Vector3f(0, -5.579, -6.747);
Eigen::Vector3f c = Eigen::Vector3f(0, -13.637, -9.751);
```

I am attempting:

```
float ac_ab_0 = acos(std::clamp(std::dot(
        normalize(c - a),
        normalize(b - a)), -1, 1));
```

but am stuck. What should this line:
`normalize(c - a)`
look like with `Eigen::Vector3f`?

Comment: You mean `(c - a).normalized()` ? . Edit: heres the quick reference guide https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html

Comment: I can't find a reference for `std::dot`

Comment: and what is exactly std::dot?

Comment: ah there is no std::dot! Is there a dot product function?

Comment: Check the quick reference guide...

Comment: `std::inner_product`

Comment: Sorry but I have to give this question a -1. Literally every part of it (and the follow-up questions) is more than trivial to find in the Eigen documentation (or via googling) - no research effort shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Eigen::Vector3f` has a `normalized()` method which returns a normalized copy of the vector.

So you could do it like this :

```
Eigen::Vector3f c_minus_a_normalized = (c - a).normalized();
Eigen::Vector3f b_minus_a_normalized = (b - a).normalized();

float ac_ab_0 = acos(std::clamp(c_minus_a_normalized.dot(b_minus_a_normalized), -1.f, 1.f));
```

You should check [Eigen quick reference](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. One last thing, how can i get the dot product of two `Eigen::Vector3f`? `dot(c_minus_a_normalized, b_minus_a_normalized)`?

Comment: I missed this point, obviously, `std::dot`won't work, I edited my answer with the correct way : `c_minus_a_normalized.dot(b_minus_a_normalized)`. Just note that if you had opened the Eigen quick reference link and searched for dot ... you would have found the solution in 2 minutes ;-)...

Comment: I just found it and clicked back as you answered! Sorry, and many thanks!

Comment: one more quick thing, if you have another minute... is there a `cross`? Can i do this? `Eigen::Vector3f axis0 = normalize(cross(c - a, b - a));`

Comment: `#include <Eigen/Geometry>`
`vec3 = vec1.cross(vec2);`

Comment: so :`Eigen::Vector3f axis0 = ((c - a).cross(b - a)).normalized();`

Comment: Thank you again. Much appreciated.